# What can I do with two blind corners ('C'-shaped kitchen)

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, custom-cabinetry

I have this space:

[image]

There is around 80cm underneath the counter, call it 70cm afer allowing for a toekick.

This consists of:

- 120cm on the left, reduced by around 9cm of wall to 111cm, of which 60cm is behind the counter, leaving a 51cm on the left
- a stove in the middle, which is lowered by 14cm, and has 21cm (side) + 90cm (tiled stove) + 21cm (side) = 131cm width of the middle area
- 150cm to the sink (out-of-shot) on the right, of which again 60cm is behind the corner (underneath the kettle/scales in the photo)

(note: the gas bottle will be moved to the basement and the hose drilled through the floor)

I have an oven currently in transit, which is 59x59cm, and which should go under the stove, where it just about fits.

Therefore from what I can see the left space I can essentially put in shelves with rarely-used junk stuffed in the back, or fit something like this:

[image]

This one is an Ikea model and is 102cm, so I believe needs a 51cm door, so possibly it would fit, however it is out-of-stock here.... There are many similar carousels at 90cm 80cm etc. however.

Just installing two shelves is much cheaper, obviously.

A 'magic corner' like this one:

[image]

seems to be the other option. However I'm not really sure about all that clunking hardware, and there aren't many choices available here.

For the right corner I could possibly build something like this:

[image]

In this case I don't think the reduced door height makes too much difference? The door is bifold and the left-hand just needs a corner cut-out of the otherwise rectangular door to fit into the space.

In this case then:

- left side carousel unit (or just shelves)
- some kind of narrow drawer unit similar to this one to fill the left 'step' in the middle (21cm wide):

[image]

- oven = 60cm
- remaining 51cm build an L-shaped cabinet (could be e.g., 51cm door in the middle and 40cm on the right side)

[image]

Does this seem reasonable?

What kind of Euro-style hinges do I need for the bifold doors?

Comment: You seem to have listed all the good options in your question.  What then is your question?    You can move everything from "Therefore" into an answer, to answer your own question.   You can mark that answer as a Wiki then people can improve it.  It's a good inventory of under-counter corner solutions.  However if there's still a question you want answered, it's not clear what that is.

Comment: It's really just what you want to trade off. The "clever but possibly hard to get locally" devices cost you more money, & some of the available space, .vs. pure shelving, which has the most space useable, but some of it is inconvenient to get to (which might be fine for rarely used things if you remember that they are back there.) I also hate the typical practice of having an empty toe-kick space under cabinets. Toe-kick concealed drawers right at floor level are great for flat things used sporadically. But you practically have to custom build those, as they are not commonly done.

Comment: The question is does this look reasonable or have I missed something, and secondly assuming that it is reasonable which specific hinges do I need for the bifold door? Once I get beyond full overlay, half overlay and inset I am a bit confused.

Comment: You could ask a new question about how to configure hinges for a bifold door.  You may find while asking it that there is already a similar question.   If you move the "answer" part of your question to an Answer you *might* get comments or more answers telling you if you've missed something.  You haven't set this up well to get answers you want.  It's a good topic worth, IMO, the effort of setting up well.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I *think* empty toe-kick space is just a cheap way of dealing with  1) Toes, so it needs to be recessed a little to take pressure off your back, 2) cabinet legs with adjustable height, 3) uneven floors, especially when tiling ends at the toe kick.   I love your point about wasted space but any drawer solution would have to contend with all those things so I guess it's easier and cheaper to just put a lid on it.

Comment: regarding the toekick space, I live in Indonesia and it tends to be damp/humid and floors get wet and mopped a lot, so while the toekick drawers definitely look nice for the wow factor, I was mainly against them on the basis that it seems preferably to build a box 10cm off the floor and stick it on adjustable plastic legs (and then cover the gap with clip on cement board), instead of having the cabinet in contact with the floor and fairly fragile drawer hardware down there.